# Changing background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have this image that I edited to make into a background so that it repeats.  It is a scan of a tablecloth.  I have been trying to get it to be yellow in Photoshop for over an hour, but every time I try to change something related to color, it only changes the lighter parts of the image.  Ideally, I would like the black to be a pale yellow, and the white to be a bit paler, and the brown to stay brown, but for it all to have a washed-out effect, making the differences subtle.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the image:
[image]

Well, I discovered the answer to my question, I guess asking it made it more clear what I was seeking. Anyway, here is what I found:

Start a new layer Fill the layer with the desired color. In the Layers Palette Blending modes pull-down, select: * Lighten * Screen * Linear Dodge and the image will take on that color. Experiment with the other blending modes to see if it can be improved upon. Once you've achieved the look, simply flatten and save.

This is from: http://photoshop911.typepad.com/help/2006/01/solid_black_to_.html

I didn't realize that trying to change black to color was different than other colors.

There you have it.

Comment: If you could take your answer make it an actual answer, and accept it as the answer, that would be great :]

Comment: Do that, if this actually gets you where you're trying to go. From your description of the problem, it doesn't seem like it would -- it's a technique for changing the color of solid line art -- so it would be great if you also posted a snippet of the final result.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson This would do exactly what he want's ....more or less.

Comment: Yeah, it's the less I'm worried about. I may be misreading his question, but I even gave that a try with his image and the result looked pretty awful, whereas a combination of masking from a copy of the red channel (adjusted with Levels) and Blend If got me to something that seemed a lot closer to the spec.

Comment: Mark this as answered or remove it please.

Comment: I don't see how to mark it as answered.  Should I delete the whole post?  Is there nothing of value to the community in the question or the comments?

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein Copy your answer from above, click the *Answer Your Question* button down below, then paste your answer. Once you've submitted your answer. Scroll down and click the *Check Mark* to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I discovered the answer to my question, I guess asking it made it more clear what I was seeking. Anyway, here is what I found:

> 1. Start a new layer
> 2. Fill the layer with the desired color.
> 3. In the Layers Palette Blending modes pull-down, select:
>
>    - Lighten
>    - Screen
>    - Linear Dodge
>
> and the image will take on that color.
>
> Experiment with the other blending modes to see if it can be improved
>   upon. Once you've achieved the look, simply flatten and save.

This is from: [Solid Black to a Color in Photoshop](http://photoshop911.typepad.com/help/2006/01/solid_black_to_.html)

I didn't realize that trying to change black to a color was different than other colors.